# Android adb can't find any android device on Centos 6 Virtualbox

Tags: android, centos, adb, virtualbox, centos6

I've prepared a fresh Centos 6.3 x64 virtual machine on Virtualbox with android development environment, also installed the guest additions with the Extension Pack for Virtualbox.

When I connect my android device via usb, Virtualbox does find it and I can attach it easily with no problems by selecting `devices` `usb devices` `SAMSUNG_Android`, then Virtualbox shows the device as connected but the android device does not show the usb connection notification any more : `USB connected` `Select to copy files to/from your computer`.

On cent terminal I try `adb devices` command and it doesn't find anything.

When I try `lsusb` on terminal before and after attaching the device, it returns the same result.

Please help me find where is the problem.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477987/android-usb-debugging-in-virtualbox?rq=1

Comment: Finally .... something relevant to my problem to read.
Thank you

Comment: Is your Host system Windows or linux? If it's linux, there could also be an issue/workaround using `udev` and udev rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory.  VirtualBox runs with `vboxusers` group permissions; android/adb run with `plugdev` group permissions, usually.

Comment: Thanks ILMostro, I've been using windows as the host machine, then I ended up installing Fedora as a bootable OS, instead of using virtual box.