# Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome

Tags: android, cordova

Have installed android on VirtualBox. I whant to debugg cordova app using Remote Debugging. But I can't to make it work.

Was trying this http://kenjane.com/adb_android_x86_in_virtualbox/ and this [Android USB debugging in VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477987/android-usb-debugging-in-virtualbox)

Host Debian Jessie. Have many versions so if you can give good advice will install needed android version.

Do not recomend android emulator, yes it wor but I have amd and Intel accelerator is not working and emulator use only one cpu from my 8320 and after 30 min off work it became to hot.

Ripple emulator do not work with file system so it not good.

Have finde this [Debugging using a virtual machine like VMWare/VirtualBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648009/debugging-using-a-virtual-machine-like-vmware-virtualbox) and now trying to do

For now I have adb and adb connection make it using this instruction http://www.mat-d.com/site/developing-android-apps-with-android-x86-and-virtual-box/
Previues insturctions is allmost the same but I do not know why, but I can do it using them. Now trying connect by chrome

For now chrome is see device on virtualbox but RSA popup to accesp debuging session not showing

For now I get it working not perfect but working. I have install android 4.4. and it blimpin for one second and I can cach it to open remote debagger))). It seems to be problem with port or some else.

Answer (score 0):

Have find this link https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77635

With that configuration works:

1) adb

2) chrome remote

3) and android can connet to localhost

What I'm using:

Host: debian jessie

Vbox: 5.0.2

Android 4.4

All works like charm)